# Remove class from one element, while adding that class to another element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question was quite hard to summarize in the title, but what I have is a group of elements with the class `panel`. When I click a panel, I add a class of `open` to it. What I also want to do is remove the `open` class if another `panel` already has the `open` class.

Here is the code:

```
  const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

function toggleOpen() {
  this.classList.toggle('open');
}

panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
```

Right now I can add the `open` class to however many panels I want, but I only want one panel to have the `open` class at a time.

Any help no how to achieve this?

Comment: In `toggleOpen` remove the class from all panels, then add it to the one you want.

Comment: Add an event listener to the ancestor that contains all the panels and use delegated event handling, it'll be more efficient.

Comment: It would be great if you would create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for people to play around with and include a link in your question. Include everything needed for a working sample, even if it doesn't quite work, including the html.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is cache the DOM node is currently selected:

```
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

let openedPanel = null;

function toggleOpen() {
  if (openedPanel)
    openedPanel.classList.remove('open');

  this.classList.add('open');
  openedPanel = this;
}

panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
```

As was mentioned, it would be more efficient also delegate the event, so if all the panels share some ancestor, you should add the event listener to that ancestor, and then from the event listener doing something like:

```
toggleOpen({target}) {
  const panel = target.closest('.panel')
  if (openedPanel)
    openedPanel.classList.remove('open');

  panel.classList.add('open');
  openedPanel = panel;
}
```

But as said they need to share a common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only want one opened at a time. You can directly target that element by getting the elements with class `open`, targeting the first element and removing class `open` before you add it to the selected one.

```
  let opened = document.getElementsByClassName('open')[0];
  if(opened!=undefined)
      opened.classList.toggle('open');
```

This way you dont have to loop or save an extra global variable.

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');


function toggleOpen() {
  let opened = document.getElementsByClassName('open')[0];
  if(opened!=undefined)
      opened.classList.toggle('open');

  this.classList.toggle('open');
}

panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.open {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var doc = document;
var panelButtons = doc.querySelectorAll(".panel");

for (var i = 0; i < panelButtons.length; i++) {
  
  panelButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    clearBlueFromButtons();
    evt.target.classList.add("blue");
  });
}

function clearBlueFromButtons(){
  for (var i = 0; i < panelButtons.length; i++) {
    panelButtons[i].classList.remove("blue");
  }
}
```

```css
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="panel">click me</button>
<button class="panel">click me</button>
<button class="panel">click me</button>
<button class="panel">click me</button>
<button class="panel">click me</button>
<button class="panel">click me</button>
<button class="panel">click me</button>
<button class="panel">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the reference of the last opened panel in a variable and then remove the class name "open" when opening another panel, below an exemple:

```
// select all panels
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
// define variable for the last clicked panel
let lastOpenedPanel;
/*
 * Add the open class name for the current panel and remove it from the previous one
*/
 function toggleOpen(
 { 
  this.classList.toggle('open'); 
   setLastOpenedTab(this);
 } 
/*
 * Set the last opened tab and remove the open class from the previous one
*/
function setLastOpenedTab(context) {
 if(lastOpenedPanel){
       lastOpenedPanel.classList.remove('open');
}
 lastOpenedPanel = context; 
}
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen))
```

I recommend the use of javascript [module pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules) to better organize and share your functions

I recommend also the use of [Jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org) to better add documentation to your javascript code

Note that the property "classList" is not supported by IE9:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these lines BEFORE “this.classList.toggle” in your toggleOpen function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++){
    panels[i].classList.remove(“active”);
}
```

Comment: While this premise is correct (although it doesn't address the efficiency issue of not using delegated event handling), you have multiple syntax errors. `forEach()` is camel-case and you're using smart quotes instead of ASCII quotes.

Comment: Careful here, `forEach` on a `NodeList` isn't supported everywhere. Better to convert to array or iterate in a for loop.

Comment: @Phix `forEach()` will be supported anywhere an arrow function would.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts I edited the forEach, but I cannot do anything about the smart quotes as I am on mobile right now. If you want to take action, go ahead. And yes, delegation would be more effective, but was not part of the request so I didn’t cover that. Again, if you would like to, go ahead.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - but what would happen if you transpiled that code? the arrow function would be successfully "converted" ... but the forEach would fail :p

Comment: [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList): *`"However some older browsers have not yet implemented NodeList.forEach()..."`*

Comment: @JaromandaX that is correct, yes. I would hope someone knowledgable enough to transpile the code would be aware of pitfalls like that, though, and it still doesn't make this answer incorrect, just (arguably) incomplete.

Comment: Transpilation isn't an issue here. `forEach` doesn't exist on the prototype of `NodeList` in some browsers, nor do transpilers check for this, at least, to my knowledge.

Comment: @Phix that _is_ the problem that JaromandaX has pointed out. A transpiler would allow the syntax to work, resulting in an unexpected runtime error on older browsers running the transpiled code which assumes (incorrectly) that `forEach()` is implemented on `NodeList`.

Comment: There, do the edits I just made satisfy everyone, excepting the smart quotes?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - *I would hope someone knowledgable enough to transpile the code* - babel transpiles, and doesn't care :p

Comment: @JaromandaX The fact you think my implication was that people transpile code without automation tools is quite absurd.

Comment: huh? I made no such inference to what you may or may not have implied @PatrickRoberts

Comment: These comments are off-topic and unnecessary. Please do not spam me.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts considering babel isn't a part of the original question or tags, this is assuming vanilla JS is used. Depending on your config this will pass through without the transpilation step catching it (been there).

Comment: @Phix thank you for repeating [exactly what I just said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883690/remove-class-from-one-element-while-adding-that-class-to-another-element-using/50883732?noredirect=1#comment88769545_50883732).

Answer (score -3):

Use an if statement to check if the element has "open" and "panel" then remove the open class. Below is the pseudo code:

```
if ((element.classList.contains(open)) == True && (element.classList.contains(panel))){
    element.classList.remove("open");
}
```

Comment: `True` is Python?

Comment: Yes, True is in python